# New object is being overwritten by previous object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying simple python class example. I have a Parent Class (person) and a subclass (contact).

I instantiate the child class two times with different objects c1 and c2. The c2 is replacing the c1 . What am i doing wrong ?

```
#!/bin/python3

import time
from time import sleep

class Person (object):
    id = 0
    name = None
    fields = {}

    def __init__(self):
        ctime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.fields.update({"create_time":ctime,
                            "write_time" :ctime})
        Person.id+=1

    def check_keys (self,vals):
        for k in vals:
            if not k in self.fields.keys():
                raise Exception("Key %s doesnot exists"%k)

    def update(self,*args,**kwargs):
        vals = kwargs['vals']
        self.check_keys(vals)
        self.fields.update(vals)
        ctime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.fields.update({"write_time":ctime})

    def write(self,*args,**kwargs):
        vals = kwargs['vals']
        self.check_keys(vals)
        self.fields.update(vals)

    def detail (self):
        print ("Model Name is ",self.name)
        for k,v in self.fields.items():
            print("key:",k," value:",v)
        print ("#"*50)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

class Contact (Person):
    name="contact"
    contact_id = 0
    fields = {
        'id':None,
        'name':None,
        'age':None,
    }

c1 = Contact()
c1.update(vals={'name':'sijan','age':31,'id':c1.get_id()})
sleep(1)
c1.update(vals={'name':'sijan Shs'})

print ("calling contact 2")

c2 = Contact()
c2.update(vals={'name':'Aurelia','age':32,'id':c2.get_id()})

print ("calling contact 1")
c1.detail()
print ("calling contact 1")
c2.detail()
```

Here is the sample output from the last 2 c1.detail() and c2.detail()

```
calling contact 1
Model Name is  contact
key: id  value: 2
key: name  value: Aurelia
key: age  value: 32
key: create_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:54
key: write_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:54
##################################################
calling contact 2
Model Name is  contact
key: id  value: 2
key: name  value: Aurelia
key: age  value: 32
key: create_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:54
key: write_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:54
#################################################
```

I believe it should be :

```
calling contact 1
Model Name is  contact
key: id  value: 1
key: name  value: Sijan Shs
key: age  value: 31
key: create_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:53
key: write_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:54
##################################################
calling contact 2
Model Name is  contact
key: id  value: 2
key: name  value: Aurelia
key: age  value: 32
key: create_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:54
key: write_time  value: 2017-03-19 15:35:54
#################################################
```

I am spinning my head around trying to figure out what is going on wrong. If i use the parent class it works smooth (the behavior as predicted i.e different data ). But i am having difficulty trying to understand why the subclass are behaving this way ? Am i missing some thing ?

**UPDATE**

What i am trying to achieve is :

I will have few more classes and each class will have their unique fields, i.e forexample address for address name. How can i Achieve this without adding the field dictionary to the parent ?
Example

```
class Address(Person):
    fields={
       'address':None
    }
```

Thanks a lot guys, 
This is working,

```
#!/bin/python3

import time
from time import sleep

class Person (object):
    id = 0
    name = None
    fields = {}

    def __init__(self):
        ctime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.fields.update({"create_time":ctime,
                            "write_time" :ctime})
        Person.id+=1

    def check_keys (self,vals):
        for k in vals:
            if not k in self.fields.keys():
                raise Exception("Key %s doesnot exists"%k)

    def update(self,*args,**kwargs):
        vals = kwargs['vals']
        self.check_keys(vals)
        self.fields.update(vals)
        ctime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.fields.update({"write_time":ctime})

    def write(self,*args,**kwargs):
        vals = kwargs['vals']
        self.check_keys(vals)
        self.fields.update(vals)

    def detail (self):
        print ("Model Name is ",self.name)
        for k,v in self.fields.items():
            print("key:",k," value:",v)
        print ("#"*50)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

class Contact (Person):


    def __init__(self):
        self.name="contact"
        self.fields = {
            'id':None,
            'name':None,
            'age':None
        }
        super(Contact,self).__init__()


ca = Contact()
ca.update(vals={'name':'sijan','age':31,'id':ca.get_id()})
sleep(1)
ca.update(vals={'name':'sijan Shs'})
ca.detail()

cb = Contact()
cb.detail()
cb.update(vals={'name':'Aurelia','age':32,'id':cb.get_id()})

print ("calling contact 1")
ca.detail()
print ("calling contact 2")
cb.detail()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name`, `id`, `fields` are class members and so new values are not instantiated when instances of `Contact` which inherits from  `Person` are made.

What you want to do is for every new instance of Contact create a new set of properties name, id, fields.

The code below does that. Pay attention to how it defines id, name, fields to be add a the instance when it is initialed ( in the `__init__` function)

Since every person has name, id, fields I dont have to initiate them in
the Contact class as well. See the definition of the Contact class for a 
cleaner implementation of the inheritance.

```
#!/bin/python3

import time
from time import sleep

class Person (object):
    # id = 0
    # name = None
    # fields = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = None
        self.fields = {
            'id':None,
            'name':None,
            'age':None,
        }

        ctime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.fields.update({"create_time":ctime,
                            "write_time" :ctime})
        self.id+=1

    def check_keys (self,vals):
        for k in vals:
            if not k in self.fields.keys():
                raise Exception("Key %s doesnot exists"%k)

    def update(self,*args,**kwargs):
        vals = kwargs['vals']
        self.check_keys(vals)
        self.fields.update(vals)
        ctime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.fields.update({"write_time":ctime})

    def write(self,*args,**kwargs):
        vals = kwargs['vals']
        self.check_keys(vals)
        self.fields.update(vals)

    def detail (self):
        print ("Model Name is ",self.name)
        for k,v in self.fields.items():
            print("key:",k," value:",v)
        print ("#"*50)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

class Contact (Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Contact, self).__init__()
        self.contact_id = 0


c1 = Contact()
c1.update(vals={'name':'sijan','age':31,'id':c1.get_id()})
# sleep(1)
c1.update(vals={'name':'sijan Shs'})

print ("calling contact 2")

c2 = Contact()
c2.update(vals={'name':'Aurelia','age':32,'id':c2.get_id()})

print ("calling contact 1")
c1.detail()
print ("calling contact 1")
c2.detail()
```

Comment: I have made some changes, and it seems to work. Do you have any suggestions ? Is this the correct way to do suffs ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are referencing class variables instead of instance variables. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables):

> Generally speaking, instance variables are for data unique to each instance and class variables are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of the class:
>
> ```
> class Dog:
>     kind = 'canine'         # class variable shared by all instances
>
>     def __init__(self, name):
>         self.name = name    # instance variable unique to each instance
> ```

Instead, you could write your classes as follows:

```
 class Person(object):
      self.id = 0
      self.name = None
      self.fields = {}
 
 # rest of the class ...

 class Contact (Person):
     self.name="contact"
     self.contact_id = 0
     self.fields = {
         'id':None,
         'name':None,
         'age':None,
     }

 # rest of the class ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Generally speaking, instance variables are for data unique to each instance and class variables are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of the class explained me enough. Cheers :)

Comment: The thing is i want to write the time stamp on create and update but if there is no init, the values are not updated. Any suggestions ?